# vscode - Cannot activate the 'Test Explorer UI' extension because it depends on the 'Test Adapter Converter' extension, which is not loaded

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I started to get this error when starting a new VS Code window:

`Cannot activate the 'Test Explorer UI' extension because it depends on the 'Test Adapter Converter' extension, which is not loaded. Would you like to reload the window to load the extension?`

When I click "reload" it loads the window and the same error appears.

Any help to resolve it is appreciated.

**More details on my configuration:**

**vs code**: Version: 1.57.1 (Universal)
Commit: 507ce72a4466fbb27b715c3722558bb15afa9f48
Date: 2021-06-17T13:28:32.912Z (1 mo ago)
Electron: 12.0.7
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.5.0

**Test Adapter Converter extension** v0.0.13

**Test Explorer UI extension** v2.20.4

PS: I also installed another extensions called Jest Runner and Jest Test Explorer.

Comment: have you found a solution yet? please i have the same thing but as follows : Cannot activate the 'Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code' extension because it depends on the 'Python' extension, which is not loaded. Would you like to reload the window to load the extension?

Answer (score 2):

you can separately install the extension from [Test Adapter Converter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.test-adapter-converter)!